# Using manual memory management with a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a variable which is referenced a lot. It started out as an automatic variable.

Now I decided that in the middle of some code I want to call its dtor to reset its state, so I intend to deallocate and reallocate it. The standard way to do this of course is to call delete on it and make a new one.

Before:

```c
void func() {
    ClassName varname; 
    while (varname.check()/*...*/) { if (varname.function()/*...*/) { /* bunches of code ... */
            /*... some more code ... */ 
        }
    } 
}
```

Now I want:

```c
void func() {
    ClassName varname; 
    while (varname.check()/*...*/) { if (varname.function()/*...*/) { /* bunches of code ... */
            if (key_code[SDLK_r]) { // Pressing R key should reset "varname"!
                /* Here I want to dealloc and realloc varname! */
                /* But if I declare varname as a ptr on line 2, */
                /* line 3 (rest of code) must be refactored. */
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

My first attempt is to go change line 2 to be something like this

```c
ClassName *varnamep = new ClassName();
ClassName& varname = *varnamep;
```

But I'm not sure if that means I'll be able to call delete on it later and reassign the reference!

```c
                delete &varname; 
                varnamep = new ClassName();
                varname = *varnamep; // I assume compiler will error here because I can't reassign a ref.
```

Can I do this some other way? Or should I just suck it up and do a find-replace for turning `varname.` into `varname->`? In this particular case for my actual real situation I will probably implement a member function `reset()` and not worry about this actual problem. But I would like to know if there is some shortcut to being able to effectively treat references as pointers (or it could turn out that this is absurd nonsense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is **not** to delete and create a new instance. Just reassign the variable:

```
ClassName varname = .... ;

....

if (some condition) {
  varname = SomethingElse;
}
```

and make sure that the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor correctly deal with resources managed by `ClassName`.

Comment: I am having difficulty finding references that explain what doing this does. Does the original allocated object on the stack get deallocated? I guess the space on the stack simply gets recycled. Do the dtor and ctor get called?

Comment: @StevenLu  Well, ann the automatic variables get deallocated when they go out of scope. There is only one `ClassName` instance alive, and it is its data members that get copied when the variable is reassigned. I put an example [here](http://ideone.com/421Z4), I hope it helps clarify things.

Answer (score 4):

Given `ClassName varname`, you *could* do this:

```
varname.~ClassName();
new (&varname) ClassName;
```

But I wouldn't recommend it.  This uses two less-commonly-known features of C++: an explicit destructor call, and placement new.  Only use this if it makes a significant difference in performance, as measured by your profiler, and the `ClassName` constructor can't throw an exception.

If `ClassName::operator=` does what you need (or you can modify it to do what you need), you can do this:

```
varname = ClassName();
```

That is more easily understood than using an explicit destructor call followed by placement-new.

Another common idiom:

```
varname.swap(ClassName());
```

This works if `ClassName` has an efficient `swap` method, like standard containers do.  This is subtle enough that it probably deserves a comment if you decide to use it.